# SyntaxError from Python Script tool written using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, buffer, syntaxerror

I am in an advanced GIS course and was assigned to create a simple tool that is used in the ArcMap toolbox that allows the user to create a buffer of 100 feet. This is the code that I have so far.

```
import arcpy
cody1=arcpy.GetParametersAsText(0)
100Feet=arcpy.GetParametersAsText(1)
output=arcpy.GetParamtersAsText(2)
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(cody1, 100Feet, output, "")
```

Does anyone know why the code is not working?

Below is the error I am getting.

[image]

Comment: Your parameters are in the wrong order **Buffer_analysis (in_features, out_feature_class, buffer_distance_or_field** from the help https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000019000000 so your tool should be arcpy.Buffer_analysis(cody1, output, 100Feet). Please don't start variable names with numbers, it is very bad practice, also consider camel/sentence casing your variables as the majority of python builtins are lower case and you could accidentally overwrite something important.

Comment: Also check the third line, looks like there is an "e" missing, it should be `GetParametersAsText`, not `GetParamtersAsText`.

Comment: I will fully admit that I just started programming yesterday so I appreciate your help. I changed the coding, is this correct?import arcpy
cody1=arcpy.GetParametersAsText(0)
Feet100=arcpy.GetParametersAsText(1)
output=arcpy.GetParametersAsText(2)
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(cody1, output, 100Feet)

Comment: Now when saving the script and attempting to use the tool it says invalid syntax (script3338.py, Line 5).

Comment: You left 100Feet instead of changing it to Feet100 in the last line. The variable name does not match anymore, you have to update all of them.

Comment: import arcpy
cody1=arcpy.GetParametersAsText(0)
Feet100=arcpy.GetParametersAsText(1)
output=arcpy.GetParametersAsText(2)
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(cody1, output, Feet100)

Comment: Now it says attribute error: 'module' object has no attribute 'GetParametersAsText'

Comment: Please update or append your new code in your question with formatting, python is very difficult to debug if it's not formatted properly. Personally I use sys.argv[] instead of arcpy.GetParametersAsText because I'm lazy, sys.argv[1] is the first parameter as the 0th parameter is the code being called. Another hint: get a *good* editor like PyWin32 or Notepad++ that changes colour when the keywords are correctly spelt; PyWin has intelisense when arcpy is imported in the interactive window so when you type arcpy. a drop down list of options appear which is great for lazy people like me.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.